# Using hitch / deferred with an xhrGet request

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm attempted to use `deferred` and `hitch` in order to provide a callback for my AJAX request. I'm using the following code:

```
//Code is executed from this function
function getContent(){
    var def = new dojo.Deferred();
    def.then(function(res){
    console.lod("DONE");
    console.log(res);
    },
    function(err){
        console.log("There was a problem...");
    });
    this.GET("path", def);
}

//Then GET is called to perform the AJAX request...
function GET(path, def){
dojo.xhrGet({
    url : path,
    load : dojo.hitch(def,function(res){
        this.resolve(res);  
    }),
    error : dojo.hitch(def, function(err){
        this.reject(err)
    })
})
```

}

However, when I run this code I get an `undefined method` error on `this.resolve(res)`. I've printed both `this` (which resolves to the deferred object) and `res` and both are not undefined. Why am I getting this error and how to achieve what I'm attempting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax methods (xhrGet and xhrPost) return deferred objects when executed. With this deferred object you can then register callback and error callback handlers for when the ajax request completes

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet({url:'someUrl'});
deferred.then(dojo.hitch(this,this.someCallbackFunction),dojo.hitch(this,this.someErrorFunction));
```

With this code, `someCallbackFunction` will be called when your ajax request returns successfully, if the ajax request returns with an error, `someErrorFunction` will be called.

For your particular code piece you code update it like this:

```
function getContent(){
    var resultFunction = function(res){
      console.lod("DONE");
      console.log(res);
    };
    var errorFunction = function(err){
      console.log("There was a problem...");
    };
    this.GET("path").then(dojo.hitch(this,resultFunction),dojo.hitch(this,errorFunction);
}

//Then GET is called to perform the AJAX request...
function GET(path){
  return dojo.xhrGet({
    url : path
  });
}
```